# Are javascript private variables really safe?

Tags: javascript, security

I'm considering letting other people inject scripts in my web page. I have a number of secrets which are known by the user, so I don't mind if for example the user opens the debugger to inspect the variables. (Real secrets and real security are of course handled in the backend)

What I do not want is to let these third party scripts access these secrets.

So here is my question : can an external code access the private members of my objects ? Or put differently : how safe are private variables in JavaScript ? I'm perplex because the way I understand it, it seems like prototypes don't really help keeping secrets.  At the same time I'm thinking that this security consideration might be the responsibility of web browsers but I'm not 100% sure here.

Thanks a lot !

Edit: I'm specifically thinking of the case where a malicious person will look at the source and deliberately write a code trying to extract the value of these private members. I want to know to which extent this is possible - if it is at all.

Edit:

I was referring to what TypeScript call "private" variables which translates to :

```
class Greeter {
    private greeting: string;
    public message: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.message;
    }
}
```

Looking at the JS, I can understand why it isn't very safe. I almost forgot TypeScript is not JS. But I'm generally talking about any way to encapsulate javascript.

Comment: If you allow someone to inject a script into your page, they have access to *everything*.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Intriguing, then why are private variables called private ? What is their point ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what kind of "private" variables you mean? Javascript has no notion of public/private and especially when it comes to referencing scripts by other scripts a concrete example could be helpful to understand what your question is really about.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks, I'll edit the question with a sample

Comment: @reddy, "why are private variables called private" privacy and security are entirely different things. The changing room in a store is *private*, but it's not **secure**. Locks on windows are secure, but afford no privacy. Private variables are used so that the details of an implementation aren't leaked out into the API.

Comment: @zzzzBov That makes sense now, I didn't interpret it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I do not want is to let these third party scripts access these secrets.

Then don't give them access to the page. Lock them away in cross-origin iframe sandboxes.

> Can an external code access the private members of my objects?

Yes. It might have to jump through some horrible hoops to do so (depending on how you implement the privacy) but I can't think of any way to reliably protect code from other code in the same JS environment.

> How put differently : how safe are private variables in JavaScript ?

Not very.

> At the same time I'm thinking that this security consideration might be the responsibility of web browsers

It is only up until the point where you load third party source code into your program.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, and thanks for the idea of using iframes.